# Update SonarQube 3.7.4 to 5.0 AddNetworkUseSubCharacteristic: Fail to upgrade database

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube5.1

**Hi:
Both I have this errror when migrating:**

The LOG:

```
2015.07.16 15:36:57 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2015.07.16 15:40:54 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  ReplaceKeyRegexpByKeySearchInMeasureFiltersData: migrating ================
2015.07.16 15:40:54 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  ReplaceKeyRegexpByKeySearchInMeasureFiltersData: migrated (0.0150s) =======
2015.07.16 15:40:54 INFO  web[DbMigration]  
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddProvisioningPermission: migrating ======================================
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddProvisioningPermission: migrated (0.1250s) =============================
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddTechnicalDebtToIssue: migrating ========================================
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_column("issues", "technical_debt", :integer, {:null=>true})
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0940s
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddTechnicalDebtToIssue: migrated (0.0940s) ===============================
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  RenameWidgetSqalePyramidToTechnicalDebtPyramid: migrating =================
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  RenameWidgetSqalePyramidToTechnicalDebtPyramid: migrated (0.0160s) ========
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  ResizeTimelineWidgets: migrating ==========================================
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  ResizeTimelineWidgets: migrated (0.1090s) =================================
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddUniqueConstraintToGroupsUsers: migrating ===============================
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- Remove duplications for 0 user group associations
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0000s
2015.07.16 15:40:55 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_index(:groups_users, [:group_id, :user_id], {:name=>"GROUPS_USERS_UNIQUE", :unique=>true})
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.6080s
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddUniqueConstraintToGroupsUsers: migrated (0.6240s) ======================
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddCharacteristicsColumns: migrating ======================================
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :parent_id, :integer, {:null=>true})
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0160s
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :root_id, :integer, {:null=>true})
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0310s
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :function_key, :string, {:null=>true, :limit=>100})
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0160s
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :factor_value, :decimal, {:null=>true, :precision=>30, :scale=>20})
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0150s
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :factor_unit, :string, {:null=>true, :limit=>100})
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0160s
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :offset_value, :decimal, {:null=>true, :precision=>30, :scale=>20})
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0160s
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :offset_unit, :string, {:null=>true, :limit=>100})
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0150s
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :created_at, :datetime, {:null=>true})
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0310s
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_column("characteristics", :updated_at, :datetime, {:null=>true})
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0160s
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddCharacteristicsColumns: migrated (0.1720s) =============================
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  
2015.07.16 15:40:56 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  MigrateCharacteristics: migrating =========================================
2015.07.16 15:41:13 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  MigrateCharacteristics: migrated (17.1290s) ===============================
2015.07.16 15:41:13 INFO  web[DbMigration]  
2015.07.16 15:41:13 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddAdministerIssuesPerm: migrating ========================================
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddAdministerIssuesPerm: migrated (14.7110s) ==============================
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]  
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  RemoveUselessCharacteristicsData: migrating ===============================
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- remove_column("characteristics", "quality_model_id")
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.5300s
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- remove_column("characteristics", "depth")
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0940s
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- remove_column("characteristics", "description")
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0930s
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:41:28 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- drop_table(:characteristic_properties)
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.5460s
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- drop_table(:characteristic_edges)
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0780s
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- drop_table(:quality_models)
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0780s
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  RemoveUselessCharacteristicsData: migrated (1.5290s) ======================
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]  
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddPermTemplateKeyPatternColumn: migrating ================================
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]  -- add_column("permission_templates", :key_pattern, :string, {:null=>true, :limit=>500})
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0.0150s
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddPermTemplateKeyPatternColumn: migrated (0.0150s) =======================
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]  
2015.07.16 15:41:29 INFO  web[DbMigration]  ==  AddNetworkUseSubCharacteristic: migrating =================================
2015.07.16 15:41:30 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to upgrade database
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ORA-00904: "DESCRIPTION": identificador no válido
: INSERT INTO characteristics (quality_model_id, kee, name, rule_id, depth, characteristic_order, description, enabled, parent_id, root_id, function_key, factor_value, factor_unit, offset_value, offset_unit, created_at, updated_at, id) VALUES(NULL, 'NETWORK_USE_EFFICIENCY', 'Network use', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 10734, 10734, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-07-16 15:41:30:245000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF6'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-07-16 15:41:30:245000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF6'), ?)
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:212:in `log'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/oracle/adapter.rb:183:in `ora_insert'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:26:in `insert_with_query_dirty'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:2967:in `create'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:53:in `create_with_timestamps'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:266:in `create_with_callbacks'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:2933:in `create_or_update'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:250:in `create_or_update_with_callbacks'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:2583:in `save'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1089:in `save_with_validation'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:79:in `save_with_dirty'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save_with_transactions'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in `save_with_transactions'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:727:in `create'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/config/../lib/../db/migrate/466_add_network_use_sub_characteristic.rb:42:in `up'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
    jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/sonarqube-5.0/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
    C:1:in `migrate'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:491:in `migrate'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:576:in `ddl_transaction'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:490:in `migrate'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:477:in `migrate'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/config/../lib/database_version.rb:62:in `upgrade_and_start'
    C:/Program Files (x86)/sonarqube-5.0/web/WEB-INF/app/models/database_migration_manager.rb:109:in `start_migration'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:228:in `call'
```

**It is that the insert is not it deletes those fields.
It is failing in this class AddNetworkUseSubCharacteristic
I can not find the problem.
And try several times to backup and restore.**

**I am migrating the basis of a oracle to another, and is exactly the same.
But this error persists.
Help !!**

Comment: I think the db user has access rights to multiple SonarQube schemas. That leads to conflicts on Oracle when migrations execute SQL requests. You shoudreduce the access rights to only the schema being upgraded.

Comment: Thanks the problem is de User Permisons